# site-to-site vpn + internet

Tags: networking, vpn, azure, local-area-network

We're considering launching an intranet solution on Azure, which we'd like to make exclusively accessible over LAN only, hence why we're considering using site-to-site VPN; LAN to Azure. Is there a way to exclude LAN internet browsing from the site-to-site VPN tunnel?

Our router / gateway is a Mikrotik device.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean you don't want on-premise users using the VPN to gain access to 'general internet things' via that tunnel? If so why not just limit the tunnel to the IP range of the Azure application and/or use split-horizon DNS so by default they only get at the application using the VPN, nothing else?

Comment: @Chopper3 thanks for your input. Yes that's correct. That would be done on the Router's end correct?

Comment: Either/both would be fine

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to exclude LAN internet browsing from the site-to-site
>   VPN tunnel?

As far as I know, we **can't** force the internet traffic through the site-to-site VPN tunnel, so the on-prem users can't use S2S VPN tunnel to access the internet by default.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you only include the Azure VNet address ranges in the tunnel configuration then it shouldn't effect your general internet browsing form on premise. Devices on premise will continue to access the internet in the same way the do now.